# Inconsistent behavior of any(df == value) on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, any

I have two dataframes `df1`, `df2` as follows

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]) 
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]) 
>>> df1
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
3  7  8
>>> df2 
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
5  6
6  7
7  8
```

When trying to check if `1` is in `df1`, it yields True as expected.

```
>>> any(df1 == 1) 
True
```

However, when trying the same on `df2`, I get, unexpectedly, `False`

```
>>> any(df2 == 1)
False
```

Despite that from a boolean perspective everything seems right.

```
>>> df1 == 1
       0      1
0   True  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False  False
>>> df2 == 1
       0
0   True
1  False
2  False
3  False
4  False
5  False
6  False
7  False
>>>
```

Any ideas on why is that?

**PS:** I am not asking about the built in any function in pandas.  I am just puzzled with the behavior of any.

Comment: I think the best is use pandas function `print ((df2 == 1).any())`   `0    True
    dtype: bool`

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for responding. I am aware of any from pandas , I am just puzzled with the behavior of any ! Can you help clarify the ambiguity?

Comment: Hard question, maybe bug (or not implemented yet). I have no idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use pandas built in `any` instead of `any` from base Python:

```
df1.eq(1).any().any()
# True

df2.eq(1).any().any()
# True
```

---

When using `any` from python, it treats the data frame as an iterable/dictionary and thus only check the column names, without looking at the values of the data frame; If you simply loop through `df1` and `df2`, you can see it only returns the column names, which is how a dictionary behaves; Since `df1` contains column names of `0` and `1`, `any([0,1])` will return `True`; `df2`, on the other hand, contains only one column of `[0]`, `any([0])` returns `False`. So `any(df == 1)` is somewhat equivalent to `any(df)` or `any(df.columns)`:

```
[x for x in df1]
# [0, 1]

[x for x in df2]
# [0]
```

Comment: What is the use of `.any().any()` here sorry? I get the correct answer with `.any()` so it's not obvious to me if they are the same or not (the only difference seeming to be that `.any().any()` removes reporting of dtype).

Comment: @roganjosh `.any().any()` will return `True` or `False` based on all the values in the data frame. While `.any()` returns result column specific.

Answer (score 3):

In pandas better use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html).

Numpy solutions:

```
print ((df1 == 1).values.any())
True
print ((df2 == 1).values.any())
True
```

Comment: upvoting for recommending to use the native function

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `(df2 == 1).any()` instead

Comment: upvoting for recommending to use the native function